# Angular 2- how can i filter Array of Objects?

Tags: angular

I have json array as below and i would like to retrieve an all the object which matched with team1Id/team2Id.

games: [{
            "id": 7935,
            "location": "Meadowbrook Ct. 2",
            "locationId": "loc-2",
            "team1": "MADE Elite",
            "team1Id": 798,
            "team1Score": "40",
            "team2": "Reisterstown Wolfpack",
            "team2Id": 797,
            "team2Score": "38",
            "time": "2016-07-09T08:00:00"
        },

```
    {
        "id": 7936,
        "location": "Meadowbrook Ct. 4",
        "locationId": "loc-4",
        "team1": "DC Premier",
        "team1Id": 801,
        "team1Score": "39",
        "team2": "Severn Elite",
        "team2Id": 804,
        "team2Score": "36",
        "time": "2016-07-09T08:00:00"
    },

    many more 
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do is use **lodash** library :

```
_.filter(games, function(game) {
    return game.team1Id === YOUR_ID && game.team2Id === YOUR_ID;
});
```

`games` : your array of json bojects

`YOUR_ID` : the id you want to compare with

Comment: Doest ES6 have a helper function for filtering. array.filter(x=> x.team1Id == YOURID);  Cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 1):

lets assume you turned you json to object form
in typescript it will look like

`list:Array<YourObject>=loadYourList();`

```
filtered:Array<YourObject> = list.filter(x=>x.team1Id=='yourID'&& x.team2Id=='your_id');
```